# No project modules after gradle import on linux

Tags: java, android, linux, intellij-idea, gradle

I have got the following root build.gradle file:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        apply plugin: "eclipse"
        apply plugin: "idea"

        version = '1.0'
        ext {
            appName = "my_project"
            gdxVersion = '1.5.4'
            roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'
            box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
            ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
            aiVersion = '1.8.0'
        }

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        }
    }

    project(":desktop") {
        apply plugin: "java"

        dependencies {
            compile project(":core")
            ...
            compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
        }

    }

    project(":android") {
        apply plugin: "android"

        configurations { natives }

        dependencies {
            compile project(":core")
            ...
            compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
        }
    }

    project(":core") {
        apply plugin: 'scala'
        apply plugin: "java"
        apply plugin: 'idea'

        dependencies {
            ...
            compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
        }

    }
```

and ones for each module:

**core**

```
   //apply plugin: 'scala'
    apply plugin: "java"
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    [compileScala, compileTestScala, compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            scala.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            java.srcDirs = []
        }
        test {
            scala.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            java.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

    compileTestScala {
        scalaCompileOptions.fork = true
        scalaCompileOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m']
        scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = [
                "-feature",
                "-language:reflectiveCalls", // used for config structural typing
                "-language:postfixOps"
        ]
    }

    eclipse.project {
        name = appName + "-core"
    }

    dependencies {
    }
```

**desktop**

```
 apply plugin: "java"
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    //sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    //sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
            }
        }
        test {
            java {
                srcDirs = ["src/test/java"]
            }
        }
    }

    project.ext.mainClassName = "com.example.my_project.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
    project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");
    task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
        main = project.mainClassName
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        standardInput = System.in
        workingDir = project.assetsDir
        ignoreExitValue = true
    }
    task dist(type: Jar) {
        from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
        from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
        from { configurations.compile.collect { zipTree(it) } }
        from files(project.assetsDir);

        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
        }
    }
    dist.dependsOn classes
    eclipse {
        project {
            name = appName + "-desktop"
            linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
        }
    }
    task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
        doLast {
            def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
            new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [kind: 'src', path: 'assets']);
            def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
            def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
            printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
            printer.print(classpath)
        }
    }
    dependencies {
    }
```

**android**

```
 android {
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
        compileSdkVersion 23
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            }

            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        }
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.my_project.android"
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 23
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        dexOptions {
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    // called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
    // the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
    // so they get packed with the APK.
    task copyAndroidNatives() {
        file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
        file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
        file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
        file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
        file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

        configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
            def outputDir = null
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
            if (outputDir != null) {
                copy {
                    from zipTree(jar)
                    into outputDir
                    include "*.so"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task run(type: Exec) {
        def path
        def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
        if (localProperties.exists()) {
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
                properties.load(instr)
            }
            def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
            if (sdkDir) {
                path = sdkDir
            } else {
                path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
            }
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }

        def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
        commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher'
    }
    // sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
    eclipse {
        // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
        // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
            }
        }

        jdt {
            sourceCompatibility = 1.6
            targetCompatibility = 1.6
        }

        classpath {
            plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
            containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
        }

        project {
            name = appName + "-android"
            natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
            buildCommands.clear();
            buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
            buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
            buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
            buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
        }
    }
    // sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
    idea {
        module {
            sourceDirs += file("src");
            scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

            iml {
                withXml {
                    def node = it.asNode()
                    def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                    builder.current = node;
                    builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                        facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                            configuration {
                                option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
    }
```

On my windows machine it's built having all three modules - core, desktop and android, but on linux no modules is found in project structure, except the project root folder. What could be the reason why behavior is different depending on platform type?

i'm using:
*idea 2016.3,
gradle 3.2.1 (for the project default gradle wrapper),*
groovy 2.4.7,
*jvm 1.7.0_80*

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that android sdk should had been setup beforehand.

Comment: Which sdk you installed, @Dmitrii?

Comment: It's been long ago, as i remember it's android sdk 4.4